# How to get value index of array inside foreach when button clicked in laravel using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, crudbooster

I want to get value index of array when I click button inside loop in blade with jquery, but when I clicked the button and send to controller, the variable always null

Code in blade

```
<form  class='form-horizontal' method='post' id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action={{CRUDBooster::mainpath('inputForm')}}>
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type='hidden' name='return_url' value={{url('admin/list_kodefikasi_pengujian')}}/>
  <input type='hidden' name='ref_mainpath' value={{url('admin/list_kodefikasi_pengujian')}}/> 
  .......   
  <tbody>
@foreach($detilKodefikasi AS $row)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $row->jenis_pnpb }}</td>
      <td>{{ (@$row->varietas!='')?$row->varietas:'-' }}</td>
      <td>{{ (@$row->kode_sampel!='')?$row->kode_sampel:'-' }}</td>
      <td>{{ (@$row->lot!='')?$row->lot:'-' }}</td>  
      <td>{{ $row->val_str }}</td>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_jenisuji[]" value="{{$row->fid_jenisuji}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="jenis_pnpb[]" value="{{$row->jenis_pnpb}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="varietas[]" value="{{$row->varietas}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="kode_sampel[]" value="{{$row->kode_sampel}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="lot[]" value="{{$row->val_str}}">
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value='Create' id="btn-save" class='btn btn-success btn-save'></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
........
</form>
```

And I have JQuery

```
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e){
            var indexIdJenisUji = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='id_jenisuji']").val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{url('admin/list_kodefikasi_pengujian/inputForm')}}",
                type: "POST",
                data:  form.serialize()+"&idJenisUji="+indexIdJenisUji },
                success : function(data){
                    function() {
                      window.location = "{{url('admin/list_kodefikasi_pengujian')}}";
                  }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert(data.error->first());
                }           
            });
        }));
```

In Controller

```
function inputForm()
{
    $this->cbLoader();
    $request = Request::all();

    $idJenisUji = $request['idJenisUji'];
    var_dump(idJenisUji);
}
```

Always return null, but when I make new function, and user alert, it's return the value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var indexIdJenisUji = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='id_jenisuji']").val();
    alert(indexIdJenisUji);
   }); 
});
```

So, if I put var indexIdJenisUji = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='id_jenisuji']").val(); at form submit and merge with form.serialize(), value always return null

Answer (score 1):

Your selector needs the brackets `[]`

```
 var indexIdJenisUji = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='id_jenisuji[]']").val();
```

or

```
var indexIdJenisUji = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^='id_jenisuji']").val();
```

Comment: still return null

Comment: why do you add the `idJenisUji` again in the data param if you have it in the `form.serialize()` ?

Comment: are you sure you got `{{$row->fid_jenisuji}}` not `{{$row->id_jenisuji}}`?

Comment: because if I click button Create it's send all value inside array id_jenisuji. Ex, if I click Create button at second index of array, it will send value of second index of arrat id_jenisuji. So I add idJenisUji and merge it with form.serialize()

Comment: yes i got {{$row->fid_jenisuji}} and i put into array id_jenisuji[]